# Running angular material for the first time

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I downloaded this code from this material angular url: https://github.com/angular/material2 for the first time. I am pretty new to angular 2. what I know is when you want to run angular, you should perform the following:
1. npm install
2. npm install -g @angular/cli
3. ng serve

Initially it complained about my typescript version being above version 2.4

therefore I install typescript 2.3

now it complains as per the screenshot. I have tried to create new project and put the file in the new project, etc and still no result. Is there any easy way to run and build the code? my npm is 5.4.2. my node js is 6.11.2. Thanks
[image]

Comment: can you show the folder structure of your angular app?

Comment: Based on the context of your github issue earlier, I'm assuming you're trying to include material2 components into your own app... is that right? Or are you trying to run the demo app inside of the material2 library (really just for development of the library)?

Comment: hi will i am trying both. in my own app and to just run the demo app straight away. just want to see it up and running whichevrr way id easier. is there any pre requisite stepnthat i miss? thx.

Comment: hi debabrata, the structure is like the one in github source data.

Comment: @WillHowell you should upgrade your nodejs and npm to the latest version

Comment: @WillHowell so you want to run the project in https://github.com/angular/material2?

Comment: yes i hav downladrd the project and just want to run it

Comment: @jay it should be satisfactory to clone the project, run `npm install` and then `npm run demo-app`. You should not try to integrate the Angular CLI with it. The CLI is for developing your own app, and there is a great guide on including Material components in your app [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started). Refer to that guide _after_ you've set up you project with the CLI.

Comment: Thanks Will. I tried it on different computer and it runs fine. perhaps wrong installation in my computer

Comment: may i know why it's npm run demo-app? normally it's just ng serve

Comment: @WillHowell hi will, I can execute npm run demo-app. however, i can't execute npm run e2e-app, npm run universal-app and other project in that source folder. it says missing script :universal-app or missing script : e2e-app. Thanks

Comment: The project is a _library_ not an application. It doesn't use the CLI at all because the CLI is exclusively for building applications, not libraries. They have their own build process based off of gulp that hosts the demo-app, watches for changes, rebuilds, etc. I can't speak for the e2e/universal apps, as I've never tried.